# What is the environmental variable that shows "executable folder" for Eclipse cdt?

Tags: environment-variables, eclipse

In Eclipse cdt, I'm trying to make a project link a library from same folder of application executable (Debug at the moment). When I set "library search path" as ${PWD} it doesn't find the library which is in the same folder with executable binary(Debug). I guess Eclipse doesn't traverse whole tree when processing the compiling steps.

I need this to make a project more "position independent". What is name of such environmental variable that lets me share my project with others so that they can build it on their own PCs despite the change of the absolute address of the library .so file on Debug folder?